# parse json data and get the schema of one record from the data

Tags: c++, json, oop, jsonschema, rapidjson

I have a sample json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "deemed",
    "University": {
        "student": [{
                "id": 10,
                "name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "def"
            }
        ]
    },
    "year": 2019
}
```

I am trying to parse this json data using rapidjson and want to know the json schema of one record. I am able to get the keys and types of every json value. Now I want to maintain hierarchies maintaining parent- child relations.

Here I have to handle two things:
1. The type of every key - This is done
2. If the key type is array/obj then how many child records are present and there types.
This all I am trying to  do for one complete json record.. Any suggestions??

My code to find the type of every key with the help of rapidjson is as follows.. 
Approach: I am maintaining a queue to store every key value and based on events thrown by rapidjson I am updating the type of every key..

My queue Node:
class Node{

```
public:
    string key;
    string type;
    Node* next;
```

};

My Handler:

struct MyHandler:public  BaseReaderHandler, MyHandler> {

```
bool StartObject(){

    //cout<<"StartObject()"<<endl;

    if(q->rear!=NULL){

        if(q->rear->type== "")
            q->rear->type = "object";
    }
    return true;

}
bool Key(const char* str, SizeType length, bool copy){
    string n = string(str,length);
    enqueue(q,n);
    //cout<<"Key :" << str << endl;
    return true;
}

bool Uint(unsigned u){

    if(q->rear->type== ""){
        q->rear->type = "integer";
    }
    return true;
}

bool String(const char* str, SizeType length, bool copy){

    if(q->rear->type == ""){

    q->rear->type = "string";

    }
    return true;
}
bool StartArray(){
    //cout<<"Startarray()"<<endl;

    if(q->rear->type==""){
      q->rear->type = "array";

    }
    return true;

}
 bool EndObject(SizeType memberCount) { 
    //cout << "EndObject:   " << memberCount<<endl;
    return true; 
 }
 bool EndArray(SizeType elementCount) { 
// cout << "EndArray:  " <<elementCount<< endl;
 return true;
 }
```

};

Myoutput:

id:integer
type:string
University:object
student:array
id:integer
name:string
id:integer
name:string
year:integer

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How does your (not working) schema looks like at the moment?

Comment: I am facing problem in maintaining the hierarchy of parent-child relationship...Currently I am looking for approach/idea on how can i create a json schema of one record... I am using rapidjson to parse json.. I am able to parse entire json and get to know each key type but how to maintain the relation hierarchy of parent and child records

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is your code? Take a look here: [mcve]